Is there a commonly used name for the units of entropy measured with base three?
Is there a commonly used name for the units of entropy measured with base three (e.g., for states $-1, 0, 1$):
$$
H=-\sum_ip_i\log_3p_i,$$
similar to bits and nats for bases $2$ and $e$?

Is there some natural "common" application you have in mind that would suggest the answer might be anything but "no"?

According to Wikipedia article Ternary numeral system:

A ternary /ˈtɜːrnəri/ numeral system (also called base 3 or trinary1) has three as its base. Analogous to a bit, a ternary digit is a trit (trinary digit). One trit is equivalent to log2 3 (about 1.58496) bits of information.


This is an appropriate answer, but I am still wondering--this is an honest question--what would be any potential use cases, especially the "common" ones you seek in your question?  Bits are popular due largely to the prevalence of binary computing devices.  I'm not aware of many ternary devices!

@whuber applications of (information) entropy go well beyond computer science, whereas the systems with three states are ubiquitous: driving directions (right/straight/left), traffic lights, spin-1 systems in physics... and anything that has to do with 3D space. I was thinking of my own term in the context of a biological application, where variables are parameter is  1/0/-1, depending on whether the related variable is more common in cases, controls or simply irrelevant. I suspected that I am not the first to think with such generic a situation.

I am not asking about applications of entropy: I am inquiring about applications where a base-3 version of entropy would be naturally adopted.  Having just three states etc. is no reason to do that.  After all, virtually every calculation of entropy with bits involves distributions that don't have exactly two states.  In that sense, your question has the scent of an "xy problem," suggesting it might be constructive to explore the underlying question rather than pursue an incidental issue of terminology.

@whuber bits, trits, or dits make sense only when the respective base is inherent to the problem. Otherwise they are as redundant as multiplying entropy by Boltzmann constant. The advantage of trits for a three state system is that entropy is $1$ when there is no preferred state (and not $1.58496$.) Same applies to any other base - I would guess that "pents", "hexts", "hepts" could be appropriate names - following, e.g., the naming conventions in chemistry... or "quints/sexts/septs" following the convention for music intervals... but these would be rather exotic.
